# Is MLE a theoretically sound method for uncertainty estimations?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, uncertainty, cross-entropy

I'm reading [Evidential Deep Learning to Quantify Classification Uncertainty](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2018/hash/a981f2b708044d6fb4a71a1463242520-Abstract.html) and it mentions that MLE is a flawed metric for evaluation uncertainty as it is a "frequentist" algorithm, but in this post [Entropy is a measure of uncertainty](https://towardsdatascience.com/entropy-is-a-measure-of-uncertainty-e2c000301c2c) and in thermodynamics they use entropy as a measure of uncertainty, which you can ascertain learning a distribution from MLE(Like Cross Entropy). My intuition is that uncertainty stemming from MLE is uncertainty about a point given the data it is trained on. Is MLE a theoretically sound method for uncertainty estimations?

Comment: I find a lot of things that otherwise respectable researchers say about the philosophical underpinnings of uncertainty quantification to be confused. ML is not inherently Frequentist; it is a method for deriving estimators, and those estimators may (or may not) have good Frequentist properties. The estimators may (or may not) also have Bayesian justifications. We can quantify uncertainty about predictions using Frequentist criteria, perhaps using the sampling distribution of ML estimators, and the predictive distributions again may (or may not) have good Frequentist (or Bayesian) properties.

Comment: @guy: That looks like an answer, might you make it into one?